# How can I include multiple CSS without overwriting the existing CSS?

Tags: html, css, templates

I am using a template (A). This has some CSS files and I want to inlcude an other template (B) in this template and the other template has also some CSS files. By including the css of template B in A, some forms are looking different because of the new CSS of template B.

How can I inlcude all CSS files of both template without replacing some forms.... Can I set a priority to one CSS? Or is there a tool where I can put more CSS files which will compress all CSS files to one?

Or can I use one CSS file to only one DIV?

Comment: Please provide more details and a code snippet in order for us to help you better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS means "Cascading Style Sheets". Here "Cascading" means that If something is found two times than the last has priority. So link the CSS file at last which you want to give priority. You can also use !important to give priority. For instance:

```
color: red !important;
```

Here red will be used overall.

Comment: Thank you, that was the solution for my problem!! Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 1):

I’m not completely sure what you are trying to do. 
However assuming you want to link more than 1 css file to page. You could play with priorities of CSS selectors. An ID for example has more priority than a Class. You could also make them more specific.

For example:

```
body ul li span {
  Color: red;
}

Span {
  Color: blue;
}
```

Here the span should be red

Comment: So I have a template and I want to include a other login template in the first template, but when I put the login inlcuding lines in the first template, everything look very different because the other css file are replacing the forms... Can I maybe use one css file to only one div and not to the full page?

Comment: Do you have a example of what you are trying to do? I think that would make answering your question easier. For example an image or some code.

Comment: I don't know how can I make a screen of a whole template, but so I try to formulate it in other words: I want to apply all the style of a .css file to particalar div in a html file, my idea was to use a <iframe> but the loading time of a iframe is a little bit too long

Comment: This is definitely possible but depends on some things. If both css sheets have selectors with the same specifity, then the 2nd file will override matching previously defined styles. Your best bet however is to make selectors in your 2nd sheet more specific. Please see this link: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: Glad I could help. But Ced makes a valid point in that you should try to avoid overriding css sheets. I’m not sure what/why you are using 2 sheets. I’m happy to help you avoid it if it is possible

Answer (score 1):

You should try to include the CSS you want for your login page only (template (B)) into your login page HTML only, like for instance:

`index.html` **file** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templateA.css">
```

`login.html` **file** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="templateB.css">
```

*The objective if simply to avoid conflicts between both template, you cannot use both of them on the same page it will cause a lot of bugs and slowdown your website a lot.*
  Please feel free to ask me in the comment if I'm not clear about anything.

Comment: Also is there no possibility to use both of them on the same page without using an iframe?